# Array iteration back to last position

Tags: ruby, arrays

I was trying to sort an array. I know I can use `sort_by`, but I was trying to implement it by myself. Here is the code:

```
def insertionSort(ar)
  for i in 1..ar.length - 1
    j = i
    k = j - 1
    while ar[j] < ar[k] && j != 0 do
      temp = ar[k]
      ar[k] = ar[j]
      ar[j] = temp
      k -= 1
      j -= 1
    end
    puts ar.join(" ")
  end
end
```

When the program reaches the first line and decrements, it came back to the last position, so the `while` doesn't break ever. I solved this with a condition in `while` to verify if is the first position.

Is this normal? Why does this happen? Is an array like a cycle list, and when I try to reach the -1 position, am I using the last position?

Comment: FYI : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Insertion_sort#Ruby

Comment: You can swap variables without a `temp` variable: `ar[k], ar[j] = ar[j], ar[k]`

Comment: I believe you did not understand when the ruby use the cyclic array. Read to post that @GaganGami attached in his comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, arrays in Ruby(like other languages) is NOT a cycle list.

It's syntax sugar. A negative index is relative to the end of the array. an index of `-1` indicates the last element of the array, `-2` is the next-to-last element in the array, and so on. For example:

```
arr = ['foo', 'bar', 42, :sym]
```

`arr[-1]` is the same as `arr[3]`, `arr[-2]` is the same as `arr[2]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it came back to the last position

When [accessing elements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Accessing+Elements), negative indices start counting from the end, i.e. `ar[-1]` is the last element.

> ... so the `while` doesn't break ever.

If Ruby did not allow negative indices, you would end up with an `IndexError`. Either way, you need `j != 0` to ensure that your loop breaks when reaching the first element.

Here's another way to write it, using an [`upto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Integer.html#method-i-upto) and a [`downto`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Integer.html#method-i-downto) loop:

```
def insertion_sort(a)
  1.upto(a.size-1) do |i|
    i.downto(1) do |j|
      break unless a[j] < a[j-1]
      a[j], a[j-1] = a[j-1], a[j]
    end
  end
end

array = [3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1]
insertion_sort(array)
array #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]
```